# Ember power select: type at least n characters before search = wrong message

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember-power-select with a custom search action for asynchronous search.

I use the searchMessage, loadingMessage and noMatchesMessage attributes (beacuse i18n).

I can test the input length in the search action, and it will correctly wait for the minimum length before doing the asynchronous search, but when I have 1 < input < minimumLength, the options show the noMatchesMessage instead of still showing the searchMessage.

Any way to fix that?